# Instantiate a POJO setting class in Spring, and make it accessible from all code

Tags: java, spring-boot, class, annotations

I'm new in Spring and I'm having problems when trying to create a class with all parameters filled by an external form. But I want to make this intance as unique, and accessible from everyclass from the rest of the project, because so far the object is being reinstantiated again, so I am not saving my settings.
I don't know if there are annotations for this, and also how I am able to inyectate this instance in any other class.

```
@Data
@Builder
public class ProjectConfiguration {

    //InputFile
    File midiFile = null;
    private String resourcesPath;
    private Sequence sequence;

    //OutputFile
    private String exportPath;
    private String exportFile;

    //Video
    private int width;
    private int height;

    //Audio
    private int sampleRate; // Hz

    //Preview
    private IMediaViewer.Mode viewMode;
    private boolean showStats;
}
```

### Can you please provide me some guidelines?

I'm updating the code as I followed the guidelines provided below and now I have more questions ans still is not working. If I use
@Autowired
ProjectConfiguration configuration;
in another class to call the same configuration it returns this error

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.kadathsound.midiread.MainView': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'configuration'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.kadathsound.midiread.model.config.ProjectConfiguration' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: projectConfiguration,getInstance

And if I remove the @Autowired then I getting a NullPointer Exception, as it is still creating a new instance.
This the new code. Please, help me. I'm completely lost with this. All the documentation I read it doesn't help me as it is not the same case.

```
@Data
@Configuration
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ProjectConfiguration implements Serializable {

    private File midiFile;
    private String resourcesPath;
    private Sequence sequence;
    private String exportPath;
    private String exportFile;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int sampleRate;
    private IMediaViewer.Mode viewMode;
    private boolean showStats;

    private static volatile ProjectConfiguration instance = null;

    @Bean
    public static ProjectConfiguration getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized(ProjectConfiguration.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new ProjectConfiguration();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a bean for this class and make it available for the entire application. You can create a config file annotated with @Configuration. Declare a method that returns the class that you want annotated with @Bean. Inside the method build the class with the values that you gather somehow return the builded class.

You can access the bean with the help of @Autowired.

I think this helps !!!.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    /** build your class like this with all the necessary values
     * and the spring will create the initial object for you and
     * inject those into all the dependent classes
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public ProjectConfiguration projectConfiguration(){
        return ProjectConfiguration.builder()
                .resourcesPath(...)
                .sequence(...)
                .build();
    }
}
```

References : https://www.javaguides.net/2018/09/spring-bean-annotation-with-example.html

Comment: You will be initializing the class inside the @Bean annotated method. Populate the details return the object of the class and you are good to go.

Comment: Hello, I think I don't understand that of building a class inside the method with the values.